# How to disable the p:dialog 'X' close button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Referring to the example for PrimeFaces (Java / JSF) to create a modal dialog,
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog.xhtml

```html
<p:dialog header="Header" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40" width="350" showEffect="fade">
    <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</p:dialog>
```

This creates a modal dialog with a 'X' close button at the right corner.
I want a solution to disable this close button for PrimeFaces dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?  Sometimes I want the close button, sometimes I don't.

Comment: @JonOnstott just do something `closable="#{yourBean.isClosable('dialogA')}"` and in your bean return `true` or `false` in the `isClosable` method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can just add `closable="false"` to your `p:dialog`. Then you will not have the 'X' close Button.

Comment: I've found that I need to use `[closable]="false"` as shown in @VIPINKUMAR's answer.  It doesn't work for me without the brackets

Comment: @Flydog57 The question is about PrimeFACES, so the PrimeTek JSF library. Not about PrimeReact, PrimeNG or PrimeVue

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way: `[closable]="false"`
to your `<p-dialog>`, because PrimeNg is expecting it as a key of the object.

Comment: Remarkable how everybody upvoted this... **_It does not work_** and it can't/won't/... since it is for prime-ng not PrimeFaces

Comment: The question is about PrimeFACES, so the PrimeTek JSF library. Not about PrimeReact, PrimeNG or PrimeVue

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close span {
    display:none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That way:

```
.ui-icon-closethick {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Just inspect that element and find the correct class to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
:closable="false"
```

as bellow

`<Dialog :closable="false">`

Comment: The question is about PrimeFACES, so the PrimeTek JSF library. Not about PrimeReact, PrimeNG or PrimeVue

Comment: I give it a thumbs up, since I can't find any answers pertaining to PrimeVue anywhere else and this worked... So thank you.